# How to route incoming non-user email id in g suite

Tags: google-workspace, email-forwarding

I use G-suite for sending and receiving emails for my custom domain lets say `mydomain`. I'm looking for a way to forward incoming emails to email addresses like `support-app1@mydomain` to another domain email addresses like `random@intercom.com` or `abc@gmail.com`.

Currently I do it by creating a user with email id that I need to forward like `support-app1@mydomain` in G-suite and then configuring the forward-email settings by signing into that user account.

There are couple of issues with it. It takes up a lot of time to just forward one email id and I have a number of email ids which I need to forward. There's no visibility. It's hard to manage these virtual users, which I've created just to forward emails and lastly, it increases the G-suite expense.

Is there a way to simply forward an email id without creating a user for it? I just need to forward the incoming emails to `mydomain` and do not care about the outgoing ones.

I tried this guide but it doesn't work https://support.google.com/a/answer/4524505?hl=en&ref_topic=2921034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your scenario, this is the appropriate steps on how to route incoming non-user email id in Google Workspace(formerly known as G Suite). Refer to the link below:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/6297084?hl=en

Comment: It took me a bit of hit and trial but this is working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I followed the [documentation mentioned](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6297084?hl=en) by @monique-g. There are lot of options, so I will mention exactly what you need to do to get this working which I learn by hit and trial. This I hope will save time for other people looking to achieve the same thing-

1. Under `Messages to affect`, check `Inbound` and `Internal-receiving`.
2. Under `Envelope Filter`, check `Only affect specific envelope recipients`. Select `Single Email Address` and mention the email address of the non-user id for which you want to forward the emails.
3. Under `For the above types of messages, do the following`, select `Modify message`.
4. Scroll to `Envelope recipient`, and select `Change envelope recipient`. Select Replace recipient and type the address you want
   to forward your email to.
5. Click Show options. Under Account types to affect, check `Unrecognized / Catch-all`, uncheck `Users` and `Groups`.
6. Save the settings and you are done.